# How to use the command "wget" to download all files which satisfy to a URL that contains 2 wildcards "*"?

Tags: command-line, wget

For example:

This is all URLs of files in website.com :

```
$ wget website.com/image/2007/dogs.jpg

$ wget website.com/video/2007/cat.mp4

$ wget website.com/music/2007/sadsong.mp3
```

How can I make this command work?

```
$ wget website.com/*/2007/* # And only download when 2 wildcards "*" isn't containing the character "/"
```

Comment: `http` does not offer globbing ... maybe you can do with a mounted webdav or by parsing/following an index site if that is enabled from the webserver.

Comment: can you get a list of all the folders / files?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117998